# Extract from a matrix all rows indexed by the components of a vector

Tags: r, matrix, submatrix

Let M be the matrix:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    3   12
[3,]    6    4
[4,]    7    2
```

I would like to extract all rows with entries equal to the components of the vector
 `v <- c(3,6,1)` from column [,1] in M producing the submatrix m:

```
         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1    9
    [2,]    3   12
    [3,]    6    4
```

I tried

```
m <- M[which(M[,1] == v), ]
```

Obtaining the error message `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`.
Using the transpose `t(v)` of `v` does not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `%in%`:

```
M[M[,1] %in% v,]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    9
[2,]    3   12
[3,]    6    4
```